# Third-party apps allowed in Android Automotive

Tags: android-automotive

The official documentation describes two kind of applications that can be implemented for Android Automotive, Media applications and Messaging applications. Also when creating a new project in Android Studio, the IDE prompts to select a template from those options.

My question is specific to **third-party apps**. Is Android Automotive limited to build one of these flavors? That is, interact with the user only through the native media UI of the vehicle or the messaging/notifications mechanism. Or as a third-party application developer I can build any other kind of applications (like generic phone/tablet android apps) with custom activities/screens? In case that any kind of applications are allowed, are they limited to run when the vehicle is parked?

Answer (score 0):

Android Automotive is Android so you could build whatever android app you like and run it on Automotive. The catch is that Google is, as per now, only allowing Media/Messaging apps into Play Store and has quite specific design guidelines that developers need to follow.
When your app follows Googles Driver Distraction Guidelines then it can run when a vehicle is moving.